# What is the difference between .* and .*? in a regular expression?

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to learn about regular exprssoins.  While investigating the difference between  `re.match` and `re.search` I saw a (disputed) claim that `re.match('(.*?)word(.*?)',string)`
was faster than `re.search("word",string)` I do not see the difference between `.*?` and `.*`  nor do I see a need for the trailing `(.*?)`  .

Comment: @Golden Lion See the post by Psychopath.  `.+` is one or more characters.

Comment: @Goldon Lion.   Whether you do as I did and (incorredtly) interpret the ? as " zero or more"  occurrences of the previous patterm, or (correctly) as changing the behaviour of * (from a greedy match to a lazy match) .*? matches  zero or more words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-6). That `?` makes `*` non-greedy, i.e., it'll try to match as few repetitions as possible instead of as many as possible.

In your example `re.match('(.*?)word(.*?)',string)`, that means as few leading `.` as possible, so try to find the earliest `word` instead of the last. The trailing `(.*?)` is indeed pointless.

Answer (score 0):

To understand any regex, the first place you go should always be https://regex101.com/. In this case, here's what it says is the only difference between the two:

> * matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> *? matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

And from there, you can then enter in example text in order to test out the expression in realtime and see what the practical difference is.